# Ошибка при добавлении шрифта times new roman для работы с python

Tags: python, шрифты, pdf, fpdf

Я хочу сохранить файл с русским текстом в pdf в pythone. Для этого я хочу использовать шрифт Times New Roman:

```
from fpdf import FPDF 
 
pdf = FPDF() 
  
pdf.add_page() 
  
pdf.set_font("Times_New_Roman.ttf", size = 15) 
  
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt = "ВПЕРЕДДДДДД!!!!", ln = 2, align = 'C') 
  
pdf.output("GFG_2_3_1.pdf")
```

Файл Times_New_Roman.ttf находится в той же папке,что и самая программа. ОДнако я получаю такое сообщение:

```
RuntimeError: FPDF error: Undefined font: times_new_roman.ttf
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Просто почитав документацию могу сказать, что для добавления кастомных шрифтов есть команда  `pdf.add_font`

То есть перед строкой `pdf.set_font("Times_New_Roman.ttf", size = 15)` нужно добавить

```
pdf.add_font('TNRoman', '', 'Times_New_Roman.ttf', uni=True)
```

О чем ошибка и сообщает.
https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/add_font/index.html

А в строке  `pdf.set_font("Times_New_Roman.ttf", size = 15)` заменить `"Times_New_Roman.ttf"` на `'TNRoman'`
Проверять не проверял, но думаю должно работать.

Comment: Как обидно чувствовать себя даже не дилетантом...спасибо!!!

Comment: Так заработало?